# Hacking decryption

Tags: aes, decryption

can you solve it for me it's aes 1836

3d3d67434f6c575a6f6c57636a316d627056476170466e62 69566e627a6c32626c68576178685761754a32596f466d5 469566e626a316d62696c335a355648616a68575970706 e62733957656c685761785a576534465765

Comment: Is this a troll question?

Comment: No It's not a troll if you know any website tell me please and tell me how to get the key

Comment: Use your brains... it's ascii hex of a reverse base64 string.... takes about 3 minutes of manual poking to get the answer

Comment: It doesn't look like a plain encoding, so it could be an encrypted text.  That said, this group is not called `free password cracking morons`.

Comment: Is there a contest going on? This is a duplicate of http://security.stackexchange.com/q/137503/8343 and another question.

Answer (score 2):

`3d3d67434f6c575a6f6c57636a316d627056476170466e6269566e627a6c32626c68576178685761754a32596f466d5469566e626a316d62696c335a355648616a68575970706e62733957656c685761785a576534465765`

is hex for

`==gCOlWZolWcj1mbpVGapFnbiVnbzl2blhWaxhWauJ2YoFmTiVnbj1mbil3Z5VHajhWYppnbs9WelhWaxZWe4FWe`

which is a base 64 encoded string backwards which when decoded is

`yaxyfqiheyolnziahchuygybnmcnubNahcbnihqiheoisnubnqiheinmcqiheiN`

which, if reversed, is

`NiehiqcmniehiqnbunsioehiqhinbchaNbuncmnbygyuhchaiznloyehiqfyxay`

which is a caesar cipher of key `f` of:

`ToknowistoknowthatyouknownothingThatisthemeaningoftrueknowledge`

or

*To know is to know that you know nothing. That is the meaning of true knowledge.*

---

The only encryption is the caesar cipher. It has nothing to do with your fictional "aes 1836"

Comment: Sounds like Ctf/homework,solving it outright doesn't really help them learn